# extract text in file between nth occurence of special character

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I need to extract text in a file between two nth occurrences of a special character. Linux "fortune" data is delimited by the "**%**" character. I have a script that counts the number of **%** occurrences then picks a rnd number in range. Now I need to extract the text **in a file** between n-1 and n occurrences of **%**.

```
#!/bin/bash
# get a fortune message 
MESSAGES=$(tr -cd % < fortune.dat | wc -c) # number of messages
MSG=$(shuf -i 1-$MESSAGES -n 1)            # rnd message in range
echo $MSG                                  # got what I expected
awk 'NR==n' RS=% n=$MSG fortune.dat        # <-- solution
```

sample **fortune.dat** file:

```
"Three people can keep a secret,
if two of them are dead!"
Ben Franklin
%
Anger is like acid, they both
destroy the container that holds them.
Chinese proverb
%
Storms make oaks take roots.
Proverb
%
If you do not hope, you will not find what is beyond your hopes.
St. Clement of Alexandra
%
```

Comment: Not sure I've ever seen UUOE before!  (Useless use of exec)

Comment: Thanks - that was a reminent from the command line testing... I removed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably the easiest way to get the text between the (n-1)th and nth occurrence of % is:

```
awk 'NR==n' RS=% n=$MSG input-file
```